# How to prevent Sequelize adding 'Id' to column name?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am finding when I do a query with Sequelize 'Id' is being added to the end of my column name, but I am not sure how to instruct Sequelize not to do so?

I have created an entity data Model for Sequelize, as follows:

```
function initializeDataModel(sequelize) {
    var dataModel = { };    

    dataModel.Playlist = this.sequelize.define('playlist', {
        name: Sequelize.STRING,
    }); 

    dataModel.PlaylistEntry = this.sequelize.define('playlist_entry', {
        playlist: {
            name: 'playlist',
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: {
                // This is a reference to another model
                model: dataModel.Playlist,

                // This is the column name of the referenced model
                key: 'id'

                // This declares when to check the foreign key constraint. PostgreSQL only.
                //deferrable: Sequelize.Deferrable.INITIALLY_IMMEDIATE 
            }               
        },
        track: Sequelize.INTEGER
    });                

    dataModel.PlaylistEntry.belongsTo(
         dataModel.Playlist,
         { as: 'Playlist', foreignKey: { name: 'playlist' }});

    dataModel.Playlist.hasMany(dataModel.PlaylistEntry);

    return dataModel;
}
```

The fields in the 'playlist_entry' table (in MariaDB) are as follows:

- id: INT(11)
- playlist: INT(11)
- track: INT(11)

The query I am performing is as follows:

```
    eagerIncludes.push(this.dataModel.PlaylistEntry);

    this.dataModel.Playlist.find({
       where: { id: playlistId },
       limit: limit,
       offset: offset,
       include: eagerIncludes                 
    }).then(function (results) {
        callback(results, options, undefined);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        callback(undefined, options, error);
    });
```

This results in:

```
ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'playlist_entries.playlistId' in 'field list'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Changing the column names in the database is not an option.

Note, this is an issue when trying to use the '[eager includes](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#eager-loading)'.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Sequelize adds `Id` to differentiate between the relationship property which is a record and the relationship key. I'm not sure you can have these with the same name without introducing serious problems.

Comment: if I am able to get the field name changed to 'playlist_id', in the 'playlist_entry' table, what changes should I be making to get this to work?

Comment: Generally it's best to adhere to the conventions Sequelize sets out unless you can't alter the schema. The defaults can be adjusted with options if necessary, but one thing you can't do is have the property and the column it's stored in with the same name.

Comment: I am working with an existing database and there are conventions, such as field and table names are all lower case and are words are separated by underscores. I am not sure I understand what you mean by "one thing you can't do is have the property and the column it's stored in with the same name". How does that represent itself in Sequelize? Any examples?

Comment: What I mean is you can't have a column called `x` and a property called `x` as those two will collide. This is why it's usually `xId` or `x_id` depending on your preference to distinguish between they key and any related record that's been instantiated.

Comment: I'll pass on this point to the DBA. In the mean time, I have a solution which works now - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some experimenting, the fix is to add the 'foreignKey' property to the hasMany definitions:

```
entities.Playlist.hasMany(entities.PlaylistEntry, { foreignKey: 'playlist' });
```